# My max target value is seen quite frequently since the data source has a threshold on what they can measure. Should I remove these data?

Tags: dataset, data-preprocessing

I'm working on a regression problem involving nutrient concentrations. The lab I'm getting my data from can measure up to 9000ppm of a particular nutrient. Beyond that, everything is reported as 9000pm. Would including these data points skew the regression, therefore I should remove them?

The model is [CatBoost](https://catboost.ai/), which is decision-tree based.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the nutrient concentrations predictor variables in. your model, or outcomes?

Answer (score 1):

No, removing those values would skew the regression, since you would be removing all the high values, so your results will be biased downwards. The correct way is to use models that allow for [censoring](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/censoring).

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into whether our methods are suited to censored data.

Comment: @VivCrowe your outcomes are right-censored (you only have a lower limit to some values), typical of survival data. Buckley-James regression for right-censored data is one approach. Such regression models are implemented by the `bj()` function in the R [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms). The [`bujar` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=bujar) evidently extends that approach to regression trees and other methods, but I haven't used that package.